# Python - running on two strings

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I'm trying to combine a for loop on a function that gets two arguments. i need to run on the two arguments (both of them are lists of integers). and it's not working for me by trying this one :

```
def xor_bytes (b, a):
    for i in range (b):
    for Z in range (a):
        if b[i]>a[Z]:
            return byte1
        if b[i]<a[Z]:
            return byte2
        if b[i]==a[Z]:
            return 0
```

Comment: How is it not working? Is it throwing an error or giving you a different output than you want?

Comment: `for bi, aZ in zip(b, a): if bi > az ...`

Comment: I'm guessing that the expected output of `xor_bytes` is a sequence of byte values. But if you return a value during the first iteration of the loop, you'll only get that single byte value and nothing else. Perhaps you meant to use a [yield expression](http://docs.python.org/2.5/ref/yieldexpr.html) instead of return - then you would be able to iterate through all the byte values.

Answer (score 2):

```
def xor_bytes (b, a):
    for i,z in zip(b,a):
        if i>z:
            return byte1
        if i<z:
            return byte2
        if i==z:
            return 0
```

1. Look at the standard library docs for `zip` or try it out at the terminal
2. Case matters. I fixed your uppercase `z`s
3. It's not necessary to use range to iterate over a list. Just iterate over the list.
4. This code won't actually work as intended, or indeed at all, because you have undefined variables

Note that your code will only actually only return one byte. You probably want to use it as a generator:

```
def xor_bytes (b, a):
    for i,z in zip(b,a):
        if i>z:
            yield i
        if i<z:
            yield z
        if i==z:
            yield chr(0)


In [6]: list(xor_bytes('hambone', 'cheesey'))
Out[6]: ['h', 'h', 'm', 'e', 's', 'n', 'y']
```

Chances are that you want this instead:

```
In [13]: [chr(ord(a)^ord(b)) for a,b in zip('hambone', 'cheesey')]
Out[13]: ['\x0b', '\t', '\x08', '\x07', '\x1c', '\x0b', '\x1c']
```

In case it's not obvious, that takes two byte strings and returns a list of bytes (or technically, length-1 byte strings) containing the result of xoring each pair of bytes.

Alternatively:

```
In [14]: ''.join(chr(ord(a)^ord(b)) for a,b in zip('hambone', 'cheesey'))
Out[14]: '\x0b\t\x08\x07\x1c\x0b\x1c'
```